# Is there a "Close all documents" keyboard shortcut for Notepad++?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, shortcuts

Using Microsoft Windows and having <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>W</kbd> to close the current window/tab in [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), I was looking for a similar shortcut to close *all* documents/windows/tabs at once.

What is possible is to press/click:

> Window > Windows > <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> > Close windows(s)

But these are a lot of clicks/keys to press.

In addition, I could simply hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>W</kbd> and keep my fingers on the keyboard until all windows are closed. Again this feels kind of a hack to me.

**So my question is:**

Is it possible to configure Notepad++ to close all open documents with a single keyboard combination?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not by default, but you can add one with the **Shortcut Mapper** (Settings → Shortcut Mapper...):

[image: Shortcut mapper]

Just double click on the item you want to change, and you'll see this window:

[image: Shortcut mapper editor]

Comment: OMG! I searched over and over through that dialog and did not see that shortcut (which was on the very first page without scrolling). Shame on me. And thanks a lot for your hint!

Answer (score 1):

**ALT+4**

This is a common keyboard shortcut to Quit in Windows.  It is not standard across other operating systems, like CTRL+W to Close.  I think it was inherited from a popular MS-DOS application, like WordPerfect.

Comment: Yes, I know :-) In Windows 8 it seems that you can use `Win` + `Q` to quit an application just like `Cmd` + `Q` on OS X.

Answer (score 1):

No, not any shortcut to close all tabs/windows in a sudden for Notepad++.